# GraphQL java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void graphql.ExecutionInput

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

Good afternoon faced with such a problem. Played with GraphQL. I made a test example and decided to move it to the main project. I don't even know how to describe this error and why it might pop up.
If someone has met with such a thing, I will be glad of your help!

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void graphql.ExecutionInput.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.util.Map)'
    at graphql.servlet.GraphQLInvocationInput.createExecutionInput(GraphQLInvocationInput.java:47) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.GraphQLSingleInvocationInput.getExecutionInput(GraphQLSingleInvocationInput.java:21) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.GraphQLQueryInvoker.query(GraphQLQueryInvoker.java:39) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.query(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:265) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.lambda$new$2(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:183) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doRequest(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:236) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doRequestAsync(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:227) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doPost(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:257) ~[graphql-java-servlet-6.1.2.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:4.0.FR]
```

I don't have any ideas. The only thing that can be is that any dependencies behave strangely, so I attach pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.techshard.graphql</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-graphql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

File vehicleql.graphqls

```
type Vehicle {
    id: ID!,
    type: String,
    modelCode: String,
    brandName: String,
    launchDate: String
}

type Query {
    vehicles(count: Int):[Vehicle]
    vehiclesall:[Vehicle]
    vehicle(id: ID):Vehicle
}

type Mutation {
    createVehicle(type: String!, modelCode: String!, brandName: String, launchDate: String):Vehicle
}
```

**And resolver**

```
@Component
public class VehicleQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleService vehicleService;

    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles(final int count) {
        return this.vehicleService.getAllVehicles(count);
    }

    public List<Vehicle> getVehiclesall() {
        return this.vehicleService.getAllVehicles();
    }

    public Optional<Vehicle> getVehicle(final int id) {
        return this.vehicleService.getVehicle(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 dependencies .

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
  <version>14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

These 2 dependencies did not swear, but prevented each other from working. Be careful. The solution was to remove the graphql-java dependency

Comment: this error is still persisting even after this change. when ever i make a new graphql request it is showing the error